# How to access multiple servers in the same SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

One database is SQL Server 2005 and other one is 2008.

I have to write a query which should pull data from both servers (I have to write a query in my local SQL box).

Any Directions?

Comment: Have you tried just prepending the table names with the database name? e.g. `[database1].[table1].Id`

Comment: It comes up with error saying cannot locate the database

Comment: If its linked you need to use 4 part notation `linkname.catalogname.schemaname.objectname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use any of the following option :

1) Linked server

2) SSIS

3) OPENROWSET

Comment: Can you explain bit more for those?

Comment: Linked server : In linked server, you can add another server to own server & fetch the records from any database of linked server. For linked server check : http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: OPENROWSET : OPENROWSET  is just like a query, we need to provide the connection string property with select query. To know more click http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2004/03/23/Using-OPENROWSET-for-moving-data-from-SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: thank you: I have used the following. SELECT *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
 'servername';'user';'pwd',
 'SELECT *
  FROM servername.[Database].[dbo].[table]'
 )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx) will also help. You can use a feature in `SMSS`, for registering servers.

Register your servers, and group them. Then just right-click on that group and issue a `New Query`. The query will be executed against all servers in the group.